# How do I see active SQL Server connections?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I want to see any active SQL Server connections, and the related information of all the connections, like from which IP address, connect to which database or something.

Are there existing commands to solve this issue?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23397001/1747983

Comment: sys.dm_exec_sessions, session id to check >50

Answer (score 436, accepted):

You can use the [`sp_who`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx) stored procedure.

> Provides information about current users, sessions, and processes in an instance of the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine. The information can be filtered to return only those processes that are not idle, that belong to a specific user, or that belong to a specific session.

Comment: when you have to filter for specific db selecting from sys.sysprocesses is better

Comment: how would I add a filter for specific databases only? WHERE dbname = 'database name' ?? I tried this and I got an error

Comment: @Geo.Dude, Iman Abidi means crafting your own select query from sys.sysprocesses and adding a where clause to that query. You'll have to filter on dbid. You can find the database id in sys.databases (or you can join those two).

Answer (score 459):

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
;
```

See also the Microsoft documentation for [sys.sysprocesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql).

Comment: When automating things, this query might be more useful than sp_who which is more oriented toward displaying.

Comment: This is my preferred method, but it doesn't fully answer the OP's question. Suggest adding `hostname` to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses to see what clients are connected. Also I just realized the Msft typo for `loginame` - is that an artifact from when column names were limited to 8 chars? lol

Comment: [sys.sysprocesses is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx) in more recent versions of SQL Server. It maps to these [three management views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx): sys.dm_exec_connections, sys.dm_exec_sessions, and sys.dm_exec_requests.

Comment: I like to `ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC, 3`

Answer (score 67):

Apart from `sp_who`, you can also use the "undocumented" `sp_who2` system stored procedure which gives you more detailed information. See *[Difference between sp_who and sp_who2](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=100099)*.

Comment: who's connected to dbo.First?

Answer (score 61):

Click the "activity monitor" icon in the toolbar.

**From [Thorsten](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2289977)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248423/#comment45563369_9815231):**

In SQL Server Management Studio, right click on Server, choose "Activity Monitor" from context menu -or- use keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

Reference: [Microsoft Docs - Open Activity Monitor in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/open-activity-monitor-sql-server-management-studio#open-activity-monitor)

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, right click on Server, choose "Activity Monitor" from context menu
-or-
use keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+A

Comment: Good option, but it requires more priviledges than DB_NAME(dbid) extraction from sys.sysprocesses.

Answer (score 51):

Below is my script to find all the sessions connected to a database and you can check if those sessions are doing any I/O and there is an option to kill them.

The script shows also the status of each session.

Have a look below.

```
--==============================================================================
-- See who is connected to the database.
-- Analyse what each spid is doing, reads and writes.
-- If safe you can copy and paste the killcommand - last column.
-- Marcelo Miorelli
-- 18-july-2017 - London (UK)
-- Tested on SQL Server 2016.
--==============================================================================
USE master
go
SELECT
     sdes.session_id
    ,sdes.login_time
    ,sdes.last_request_start_time
    ,sdes.last_request_end_time
    ,sdes.is_user_process
    ,sdes.host_name
    ,sdes.program_name
    ,sdes.login_name
    ,sdes.status

    ,sdec.num_reads
    ,sdec.num_writes
    ,sdec.last_read
    ,sdec.last_write
    ,sdes.reads
    ,sdes.logical_reads
    ,sdes.writes

    ,sdest.DatabaseName
    ,sdest.ObjName
    ,sdes.client_interface_name
    ,sdes.nt_domain
    ,sdes.nt_user_name
    ,sdec.client_net_address
    ,sdec.local_net_address
    ,sdest.Query
    ,KillCommand  = 'Kill '+ CAST(sdes.session_id  AS VARCHAR)
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sdes

INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS sdec
        ON sdec.session_id = sdes.session_id

CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) AS DatabaseName
        ,OBJECT_NAME(objectid) AS ObjName
        ,COALESCE((
            SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(definition)]
            FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ), '') AS Query

    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)

) sdest
WHERE sdes.session_id <> @@SPID
  AND sdest.DatabaseName ='yourdatabasename'
--ORDER BY sdes.last_request_start_time DESC

--==============================================================================
```

UPDATE 20th Jan 2022

I have now a better version that uses [sys.dm_tran_locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
This is particularly useful when you need all users off an specific database, and that's why I have this parameter `@dbname`

Even if someone just opens SSMS and connect to a database it will show up in this query.

```
DECLARE @dbname SYSNAME =NULL

SELECT 
        sdes.session_id 
       ,sdes.login_time 
       ,sdes.last_request_start_time
       ,sdes.last_request_end_time
       ,sdes.is_user_process
       ,sdes.host_name
       ,sdes.program_name
       ,sdes.login_name
       ,sdes.status

       ,sdec.num_reads
       ,sdec.num_writes
       ,sdec.last_read
       ,sdec.last_write
       ,sdes.reads
       ,sdes.logical_reads
       ,sdes.writes
       
       ,DatabaseName = COALESCE( db_name(sdes.database_id),  N'')
       ,sdest.ObjName
    ,sdes.client_interface_name
    ,sdes.nt_domain
    ,sdes.nt_user_name
    ,sdec.client_net_address
    ,sdec.local_net_address
    ,sdest.Query
    ,KillCommand  = 'Kill '+ CAST(sdes.session_id  AS VARCHAR)

from sys.dm_tran_locks t
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sdes
        ON t.request_session_id = sdes.session_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS sdec 
        ON sdec.session_id = sdes.session_id

OUTER APPLY (

                SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) AS DatabaseName
                    ,OBJECT_NAME(objectid) AS ObjName
                    ,COALESCE((
                            SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(definition)]
                            FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle) 
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                                ,TYPE
                            ), '') AS Query

                FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)

    ) sdest
where t.resource_type = 'database' 
  and t.resource_database_id = CASE WHEN @dbname IS NULL 
                                    THEN t.resource_database_id  
                                    ELSE DB_ID(@dbname)  
                               END 
  and t.request_type = 'LOCK' 
  and t.request_status = 'GRANT'
```

Comment: This is great. Actually shows me the query!

Comment: @JacobIRR Yes however, now I use a mix of that with this one: `select request_session_id
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where resource_type = 'database' and
      resource_database_id = 3 and
      request_type = 'LOCK' and
      request_status = 'GRANT';`

Comment: I will update the answer because It has helped me a lot really

Comment: Note: capital 'T' in line " ON T.request_session_id" 
should be 't'  : 
'ON t.request_session_id' (could not edit the answer)

Answer (score 22):

MS's query explaining the use of the [`KILL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql) command is quite useful providing connection's information:

```
SELECT conn.session_id, host_name, program_name,
    nt_domain, login_name, connect_time, last_request_end_time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sess
JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS conn
   ON sess.session_id = conn.session_id;
```

Answer (score 16):

I threw this together so that you could do some querying on the results

```
Declare @dbName varchar(150)
set @dbName = '[YOURDATABASENAME]'

--Total machine connections
--SELECT  COUNT(dbid) as TotalConnections FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE dbid > 0

--Available connections
DECLARE @SPWHO1 TABLE (DBName VARCHAR(1000) NULL, NoOfAvailableConnections VARCHAR(1000) NULL, LoginName VARCHAR(1000) NULL)
INSERT INTO @SPWHO1 
    SELECT db_name(dbid), count(dbid), loginame FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE dbid > 0 GROUP BY dbid, loginame
SELECT * FROM @SPWHO1 WHERE DBName = @dbName

--Running connections
DECLARE @SPWHO2 TABLE (SPID VARCHAR(1000), [Status] VARCHAR(1000) NULL, [Login] VARCHAR(1000) NULL, HostName VARCHAR(1000) NULL, BlkBy VARCHAR(1000) NULL, DBName VARCHAR(1000) NULL, Command VARCHAR(1000) NULL, CPUTime VARCHAR(1000) NULL, DiskIO VARCHAR(1000) NULL, LastBatch VARCHAR(1000) NULL, ProgramName VARCHAR(1000) NULL, SPID2 VARCHAR(1000) NULL, Request VARCHAR(1000) NULL)
INSERT INTO @SPWHO2 
    EXEC sp_who2 'Active'
SELECT * FROM @SPWHO2 WHERE DBName = @dbName
```

Answer (score 9):

You can perform the following T-SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE status = 'running';
```