# Connecting with hibernate to a Microsoft SQL 2008 server

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL 2008 server via hibernate.
The following is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```xml
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=myDBName;instanceName=myInstanceName;</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>

        <mapping resource="Obj.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is the code I use to try and establish an connection and do a query :

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class SessionsTest {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sessionFactory = configureSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Obj> result = (List<Obj>) session.createQuery("FROM Obj").list();

        for (Obj obj : result ) {
            System.out.println(obj.getObjID());
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        if ( sessionFactory != null ) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }

    private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();            
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

The stacktrace I get :

```
2013-04-13 15:02:03,449 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2013-04-13 15:02:03,449 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The TCP/IP connection to the host 127.0.0.1, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1425)
    at com.test.test.ObjTest.main(ObjTest.java:24)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 127.0.0.1, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1033)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 5 more
```

I have tried using a different driver(JTDS).
I have tried changing the URL string in various ways.
I have tried changing my dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect.
I also tried using windows authentication at one point by adding ;IntegratedSecurity=true to the end of the url string.
Other than this I have been poking around in the server properties to make sure the the instance I am providing is correct aswell as the port.I have tried : telnet localhost 1433 and can't connect that way,but I can connect using SQL Server Management Studio.
Further I used NetStat -o in cmd and TaskList /FI "PID eq 4072" /FO LIST /V to try and track down the sql server to confirm the port aswell.The weird thing is I couldn't track down sql server this way.It does not turn up in the NetStat list,but if I use the PID of the server directly it does show details about it except the Status is Unknown,Session# is 0 and User Name is N/A.

I use Hibernate 4.2.0 and SQLJDBC4,when I used JTDS it was 1.2.7.
The output of java -version :
java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode)

Please tell me if any other info is needed,first time posting here.

Comment: SQL studio could use pipes, not socket. Until you tune your SQL server to listen on a port, there is no point to do anything in Java. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518823/how-to-find-the-port-for-ms-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your SQL Server instance is not serving at 1433 for TCP connections. 
**To identify the port:**

- Go to SQL Server configuration manager.
- Choose SQL Server Network Configuration

  - Go for Protocols for Your Instance
  - Click on **TCP IP** (Enable it if not enabled, then clients could connect with TCP/IP)
  - On the popup which results, Choose **IP Addresses Tab**
  - Scroll Down
  - You'll see TCP Dynamic ports in Section **IPAll**
  - Grab that value and that's the port you should be using

Comment: Thanks alot for the response,this fixed my problem,turns out TCP IP was disabled and Dynamic Ports aswell.Unfortunately can't vote up your answer otherwise I would.

Answer (score 7):

Really, really, really check if the TCP/IP protocol is enabled in your SQL Server instance.

Follow these steps (tested for SS2012) to make sure:

- Open "**Sql Server Configuration Manager**" in "Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2012\Configuration Tools\"
- Expand "SQL Server Network Configuration"
- Go in "Protocols for `<YourInstance>`"
- Enable TCP/IP

If you have any problem, check [this blog post](http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/connecting-to-sql-server-using-jtds/) for details, as it contains screenshots and much more info.

Also check if **the "SQL Server Browser" windows service is activated and running**:

- Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
- Open "SQL Server Browser" service and enable it (make it manual or automatic, depends on your needs)
- Start it.

That's it.

After I installed a fresh local SQL Server, all I had to do was to enable TCP/IP and start the SQL Server Browser service.

Below a code I use to test the connection to a `SQLEXPRESS` local instance. Of course, you should change the IP, DatabaseName and user/password as needed.:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JtdsSqlExpressInstanceConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;instance=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=master";
        String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "user";
        String password = "password";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to the database!!! Getting table list...");
            DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
            rs = dbm.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] { "TABLE" });
            while (rs.next()) { System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")); }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conn.close();
            rs.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And if you use Maven, add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response,unfortunately I can't accept two answer or vote up,but this would also have worked ofcourse.

Comment: Thanks for the "check if the "SQL Server Browser" windows service is activated and running" section. Saved me!