# Standard Port MS SQL vs. BO

Tags: sql-server, business-objects

What is the standard port between MS SQL Server (where the database resides) and Business Objects Server?
(I am having problems with report creation with WEBI and Rich Client in BO.)
I am getting this error message:

> Datenbankfehler: [Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0] : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. . (IES 10901) (WIS 10901)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518823/how-to-find-the-port-for-ms-sql-server-2008

There isn't a designated port between applications, SQL Server just listens on a certain port.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like  connecting to SQL Server problem. The port for SQL Server is 1433. What you can do is

I used SQL SERVER 2008, you can use the right one.

Under the  section of the file, change the following two parameters:
Parameter Provider CLSID " change value to: SQLOLEDB
Parameter Enumerator CLSID " change value to: SQLOLEDB Enumerator

**SERVER NAME should be exact- No TYPO**

and more info

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx