# Seriate SqlContext Error. Failed on step 'connecting'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, node.js

I'm new to Nodejs and I have to implement some changes in an small project. It runs over Sql Server using [seriate](https://github.com/LeanKit-Labs/seriate) module. I throws this error...

> Seriate SqlContext Error. Failed on step 'connecting'.Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:undefined in 15000ms

when executing a [`getPlainContext()`](https://github.com/LeanKit-Labs/seriate#getplaincontextconnectionconfig) with the following config object:

```
{
    "user": "node",
    "password": "node",
    "server": "127.0.0.1\\SQLEXPRESS",
    "database": "lms-db-dev"
}
```

I already tryied using `(local)\\SQLEXPRESS` which I'm using on my Web.config file connection string:

```
Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=lms-db-dev;user id=node; password=node
```

I'm wondering why it tryies to connect to `127.0.0.1:undefined` and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the driver doesn't works with instance name, but Ip/port only. So I removed the instance name and added the `port` property on the config object with my local server's port, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21087689/1267304). My config object becames this:

```
"db": {
    "user": "node",
    "password": "node",
    "server": "127.0.0.1",
    "database": "lms-db-dev",
    "port": "52519"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to turn on the SQL Server Browser service to get Seriate to work with the instance name.

[image: SQL server configuration manager]