# How to get detailed list of connections to database in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, database-connection, connection-pooling

How to get detailed list of connections to database in sql server 2005?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23397001/1747983

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the system stored procedure `sp_who2`.

Answer (score 19):

sp_who2 will actually provide a list of connections for the *database server*, not a *database*.  To view connections for a single database (YourDatabaseName in this example), you can use

```
DECLARE @AllConnections TABLE(
    SPID INT,
    Status VARCHAR(MAX),
    LOGIN VARCHAR(MAX),
    HostName VARCHAR(MAX),
    BlkBy VARCHAR(MAX),
    DBName VARCHAR(MAX),
    Command VARCHAR(MAX),
    CPUTime INT,
    DiskIO INT,
    LastBatch VARCHAR(MAX),
    ProgramName VARCHAR(MAX),
    SPID_1 INT,
    REQUESTID INT
)

INSERT INTO @AllConnections EXEC sp_who2

SELECT * FROM @AllConnections WHERE DBName = 'YourDatabaseName'
```

(Adapted from [SQL Server: Filter output of sp_who2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234691/sql-server-filter-output-of-sp-who2).)

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I just need to list connections to a single Database instead of the whole instance.

Answer (score 13):

As @Hutch pointed out, one of the major limitations of `sp_who2` is that it does not take any parameters so you cannot sort or filter it by default.  You can [save the results into a temp table](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/sp_who2%20-%20filtering%20and%20sorting%20the%20results.aspx), but then the you have to declare all the types ahead of time (*and remember to `DROP TABLE`*).

Instead, you can just go directly to the source on `master.dbo.sysprocesses`

I've constructed this to output almost exactly the same thing that `sp_who2` generates, except that you can easily add `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` clauses to get meaningful output.

```sql
SELECT  spid,
        sp.[status],
        loginame [Login],
        hostname, 
        blocked BlkBy,
        sd.name DBName, 
        cmd Command,
        cpu CPUTime,
        physical_io DiskIO,
        last_batch LastBatch,
        [program_name] ProgramName   
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses sp 
JOIN master.dbo.sysdatabases sd ON sp.dbid = sd.dbid
ORDER BY spid
```

Comment: You should consider using [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) since [sys.sysprocesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx) is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [who is active?](http://whoisactive.com):

> Who is Active? is a comprehensive
>   server activity stored procedure based
>   on the SQL Server 2005 and 2008
>   dynamic management views (DMVs). Think
>   of it as sp_who2 on a hefty dose of
>   anabolic steroids