# Getting the list of users accessing the sql server

Tags: sql

I want to get the list of users accessing the sql server(database like tables/views),my users will access the views from excel sheet.

How to Track the user connecting to sql databse?

Comment: This is already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654291/how-to-get-detailed-list-of-connections-to-database-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: there they says that sp_who2 will solve there issue but in my case users are connecting from External sourece to datbase base using the Domain logins.my requirement is to track the users who are accessing to sql databse

Comment: As per my knowledge sp_who2 will give only the active users right but i have a requirmenet to get the history of users

Comment: I tried like these  select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions but it gaves only my users bcoz i only the person using the prod server from managment studion rest all of them access from Excel sheets

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get detailed list of connections to database in sql server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654291/how-to-get-detailed-list-of-connections-to-database-in-sql-server-2005)