# Drop SQL login even while logged in

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When dropping a SQL Server 2008 login as part of integration test execution I sometimes get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Could not drop login 'SomeTestUser' as
>   the user is currently logged in.

I don't care if it's logged in - I still want to drop it. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 62):

OK, here's the script I came up with, which worked for me. Note that you need to be a member of the **processadmin** server role to find and kill the connection and a member of **securityadmin** to drop the login. (Of course, **sysadmin** can do anything.)

```
DECLARE @loginNameToDrop sysname
SET @loginNameToDrop = '<victim login ID>';

DECLARE sessionsToKill CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT session_id
    FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
    WHERE login_name = @loginNameToDrop
OPEN sessionsToKill

DECLARE @sessionId INT
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(200)

FETCH NEXT FROM sessionsToKill INTO @sessionId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Killing session ' + CAST(@sessionId AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' for login ' + @loginNameToDrop

    SET @statement = 'KILL ' + CAST(@sessionId AS NVARCHAR(20))
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement

    FETCH NEXT FROM sessionsToKill INTO @sessionId
END

CLOSE sessionsToKill
DEALLOCATE sessionsToKill

PRINT 'Dropping login ' + @loginNameToDrop
SET @statement = 'DROP LOGIN [' + @loginNameToDrop + ']'
EXEC sp_executesql @statement
```

Answer (score 18):

User can be deleted after killing the session by identifying the `session_id` of the user.

```
SELECT session_id
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE login_name = 'test'

KILL 69  --69 is session_id here, you may get different id
```

Now you can delete the login simply by executing the below query (or) by using sql server management studio options.

```
DROP LOGIN 'test'
```

Answer (score 9):

In SqlServer Studio on the Master DB.

Use the command sp_who2 to list the opened sessions.

In the list find the spid for your user - there may be more than one - e.g. 999

Use kill and the spid to close all the sessions e.g.: kill 999

Then DROP LOGIN [theuser]

Comment: Cannot kill your own process

Comment: I believe the original question was about dropping a login, not your own. I haven't been using SQL server for a while now so I can't tell you what to do if you want to drop your own login. Maybe simply log out in all the windows you logged in.

Comment: If you need to filter the results of sp_who2, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234691/sql-server-filter-output-of-sp-who2

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE_NAME]
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

as SqlACID said, or you could find all processes and kill one at time and then drop user

Comment: BTW, if you need to restore the DB to its original status use the same command with the MULTI_USER option. Cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3):

This may not always be applicable but I've just restarted the SQL server from services. That cleared up any open connections.

Comment: I had to also delete the databases with the service restart

Comment: Isn't it a tiny bit overkill to restart the instance just to get rid of a single login/user?

Comment: Of course it is but I found it to be the easiest method when in development.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what database they will be connected to, you could set the database to single user mode, with rollback immediate, that'll drop their sessions.

Comment: Yes, I do this. In fact, I actually drop their database first, but sometimes (very rarely) this error still occurs.

Comment: I suppose you could get the spid of the account's connections from sys.sysprocesses and build a 'KILL '+ spid statement to execute.