# How can I view just the SQL statements SQL Server is executing

Tags: sql-server

Does SQL Server have the equivalent of tailing the log in MySQL?

It's really simple way to debug web apps. However I can't find a way to do this in SQL Server.

When I use the profiler I am given many options when starting a new trace. I can get it to output the SQL that is executed from management studio but not my app (it's definitely pointed at the same instance).

Comment: Maybe [SQL Server: Filter output of sp_who2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2234691/205233) has something for you.

Comment: So the question is how to filter out your application in Profiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server Profiler is the right tool for the job, normally I use these settings (out of lazyness because these are more-or-less the defaults) and it should show all queries run against the SQL instance that you are connected to

[image: Screenshot of SQL Server profiler settings]

If you don't see all the queries you are expecting then there are a couple of things to try:

- Check the Column Filters - you might have a filter (e.g. on database) that you were not aware of
- Check `SQL:BatchCompleted` and `RPC:Completed` are both selected - queries run will appear under one of these events depending on whether its a stored procedure or an ad-hoc query being run.

If you still don't see your query under here then I would double check that your application is running queries and that they are running against the correct database (SQL Profiler is normally the method I use to verify this if I'm in any doubt)

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the really quick response.

Comment: SQL Server Profiler has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16). Use [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver16) or [SSMS XEvent Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-ssms-xe-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) instead