# SQL Server Active Sessions

Tags: sql-server

How to get active sessions details with database and object details in SQL Server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I see active SQL Server connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248423/how-do-i-see-active-sql-server-connections)

Answer (score 3):

The [**sys.dm_exec_sessions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) view  reports all authenticated  sessions within SQL Server. 
You can use the following query;

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

For more detailed query you can use this;

```
SELECT s.session_id, s.login_time, s.host_name, s.program_name,
s.login_name, s.nt_user_name, s.is_user_process,
s.database_id, DB_NAME(s.database_id) AS [database], 
s.status,
s.reads, s.writes, s.logical_reads, s.row_count,
c.session_id, c.net_transport, c.protocol_type, 
c.client_net_address, c.client_tcp_port, 
c.num_writes AS DataPacketWrites 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c
ON s.session_id = c.session_id 
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r 
ON s.session_id = r.session_id
```